# iOS app submit for review fails 'UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities'

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am getting an error when attempting to submit my new app version for review through iTunes Connect. This is the error I am getting:

> The app's Info.plist can't contain values for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key that would prevent this app from opening on any iOS device that was supported by previous versions. For more information, see Understanding the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Key.

In every build previously released of this app, I have listed the following attribute under "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" in the plist file:

```
armv7
```

In this latest build I have included some features dependent on location so I have increased the required capabilities to:

```
armv7, location-services, gps
```

This now causes my build to throw the above error message on submission. Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Currently, I have attempted bumping the version and tried removing 'armv7' from the required capabilities.

Comment: i just removed this key from plist and upload app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Device Compatibility for iTunes submissions.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

Here is the relevant section:

> Important: All device requirement changes must be made when you submit
>   an update to your binary. You are permitted only to expand your device
>   requirements. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your
>   device requirements is not permitted. You are unable to restrict
>   device requirements because this action will keep customers who have
>   previously downloaded your app from running new updates.

So the short answer is, you cannot do that. If you absolutely must have those flags, then you will need to create a new app for it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, that devices where the app was installed previously and don't support these capabilities "won't" be able to update the app, and that's why you get this error

So I don't think you will be able to put them there.

Answer (score 0):

I originally asked the question, but I am commenting because I was able to submit the app for review by removing the 'gps' device capability.